# could not load a very simple module in a karma test

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I could not load a very simple angular module into the karma test.

My module looks, (karmatest_test0.js)

The module has no controllers/services. Just for simplest.

```
'use strict';

var stackoverflow_test = angular.module("stackoverflow_test_app", []);
```

My test looks,(karmatest\test0.js)

The only thing I did here is to load this module

```
'use strict';

describe("stackoverflow_test", function(){

  it("init the service", function(){

      var $injector = angular.injector(['stackoverflow_test_app']);

      expect(true).toBe(true);

  });

});
```

My configuration file looks, (my.conf.js)

Everything the most basic. I did include angular.js and angular-mock.js from the Google CDN.

```
    // Karma configuration
    // Generated on Wed Oct 28 2015 18:37:16 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

    module.exports = function(config) {
      config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',


        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [          

'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js',
          'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-mocks.js',
          'karmatest_test.js',
          'karmatest/*.js'
        ],


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
        ],

        reporters: ['mocha', 'html'],

        port: 9876,

        colors: true,

        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        autoWatch: true,

        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

        singleRun: true,

        concurrency: Infinity
      })
    }
```

Everything is the simplest. The error is,

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr]

 at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:35
    at r (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:7)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:35)
    at ab (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:38)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/karmatest/test0.js?7c002471b6c0067e24cfb8de0e5048f9581f112e:19
```

It looks the error stems from my test would not load module "stackoverflow_test". How come?

Comment: FYI, you get better (more verbose) error messages if you use the un-minified versions of Angular, angular-mocks, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is supposed to be the creation of your module, you should pass **two arguments** to `angular.module`; the name and array of dependencies.

```
var stackoverflow_test = angular.module("stackoverflow_test_app", []);
```

Otherwise, it acts as a *getter*. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module#usage

---

Also, your file *seems* to be named `karmatest_test0.js` yet your Karma `conf.js` requires `karmatest_test.js`.